# How to Read a Local File Using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a relatively simple task that I want to achieve, but I am totally stumped on how to achieve it. I want to create an HTML page that allows users to select a local JSON file. I want to pass the path to this local file to some Javascript code. Then I want to read that file using Javascript every time the file changes.

I've investigated a few different methods for achieving this. First, I tried just using Javascript. This worked great until I wanted to read the file multiple times as it was changing. Evidently there are security concerns that make this impossible.

Next, I investigated using Node.js to solve this problem. It has some file utilities that seem perfect, and it's server-side, which may help with the security issues. But using just Node, I couldn't figure out how to select a local file in HTML and pass the path to the Javascript code. From investigation online, it seems like Express.js would be useful.

So now I'm trying to use Node.js and Express.js. Now I can figure out the file name from an HTML form! But I can't figure out the path to the local file so that I can read it using the Node file utilities... From looking at similar questions online, it looks like everyone uploads files, then reads them. Is that what I have to do with Express? If so, is it possible for me to monitor changes to the original file, upload the file when those changes get made, then read the changed file? Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, does anyone have any recommendations on libraries/modules to use? Thank you so much for any help - please let me know if I can be more clear about anything.

Comment: The server has no access to the client's filesystem.

Comment: It is impossible to detect local file changes via browser

Comment: @Slaks: so does this mean it's impossible to have a server that can read a file when it changes? I'm a little confused, because Node has the Filesystem module that allows you to read a local file, right?

Comment: @MysterX: I'm sorry, I'm dumb, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "via browser." Would you mind expanding on that?

Comment: @user2701114: Exactly.  A _local_ file.  As opposed to a file on the end-user's computer.

Comment: JavaScript code in web application executes in browser and browser blocks attempts of javascript to get access to local user's file system

Comment: You need to understand the difference between the server and the client.

Comment: @SLaks: Ah, gotcha - like I said in the original question, the file I want to read/monitor is a local file. Do you have any advice on how I can read and monitor a local file using a server?

Comment: You can't.  The server has no access to the client.

Comment: @SLaks: But if it's a local file, then I know that I can use Node to at least read the file, right?

Comment: @user2701114: Local _to which computer_?

Comment: @SLaks: the file is on the client system. The server is running from the client system.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener

Comment: @SLaks: Yep, so I tried using that, and it seemed like it would be really appropriate, but, like I said in my question above, I couldn't figure out how to pass the path of a user-selected file to the Javascript code (the File System routines). In all the examples I've seen of File System, users just hard code the name/path of the file they want to read. Thanks for bearing with me on this!

Comment: The browser will not give you a path.

Comment: @SLaks: so I'm trying to let the user specify a file on the local system (via an HTML form), then have the server (residing on the same system) read that file: is that impossible?

Comment: The browser will only send the content, not the path.

Comment: @user2701114 Did you find any solution ? Or just ended up with reading files on server only.